# PHP Exec returning incorrect process ID

Tags: php, shell, lamp, pid

I am using PHP to launch an FFMPEG transcoding command. It's a typical LAMP setup running on Ubuntu 10.04 Server, there's nothing special about the configuration.

The issue I am having is when I run the PHP Exec command it returns the incorrect process ID. Instead of returning the proper PID, it instead returns one that is 2 higher. i.e. the FFMPEG process id would be 3557 but PHP Exec returns 3559.

I have consistently managed to produce this everytime. The problem is, I really need the correct process ID so I can stop the process later if I choose to.

The FFMPEG command works and starts without a problem, so I do not think it is the source of the issue:

```
$cmd = "ffmpeg -r 4 -f mjpeg -an -i 'http://" . $internalhost . ":" . $stream_port . "'
-vcodec libx264 -vpre fastfirstpass -vpre baseline -b 24k -bt 32k -threads 0 
http://localhost:8090/" . $localport . ".ffm";
$ffmpg = new Process($cmd);
```

I know... it's pretty ugly, but it works and I don't think the variables are important.

To launch the code I am using a class from the PHP Manual website which is as follows:

```
class Process
{
private $pid;
private $command;

public function __construct($cl=false){
    if ($cl != false){
        $this->command = $cl;
        $this->runCom();
    }
}
private function runCom(){
    $command = 'nohup '.$this->command.' > /dev/null 2> /dev/null & echo $!';
    exec($command ,$op);
    $this->pid = (int)$op[0];
}

public function setPid($pid){
    $this->pid = $pid;
}

public function getPid(){
    return $this->pid;
}

public function status(){
    $command = 'ps -p '.$this->pid;
    exec($command,$op);
    if (!isset($op[1]))return false;
    else return true;
}

public function start(){
    if ($this->command != '')$this->runCom();
    else return true;
}
public function stop(){
    $command = 'kill '.$this->pid;
    exec($command);
    if ($this->status() == false)return true;
    else return false;
}
}
```

What I guess is happening is that for some reason FFMPEG is kicking off another 2 processes and instead of returning the PID for the main process, it is returning the PIDs for the last process.

Could be wrong though, but am still scratching my head.

Answer (score 0):

The process ID is coming from the `echo $!`, and the Bash manual states that `$!` "Expands to the process ID of the most recently executed background (asynchronous) command."  I would have the same hunch as you that FFMPEG is spawning additional processes, at least one of which is in the background, and `$!` consequently picks up on it.  Could you run some additional tests to check this?  First, instead of 'ffmpeg', run something long lived as `$cmd` which you know won't spawn background processes, such as `md5sum /dev/zero`, and see if the process ID you get from `getPid()` matches what you see in `ps`.  Second, when you run your original code, what does `ps X` (on the command line) say is running, where X is the number reported by `getPid()`?  Does running `ps fwax | grep -3 X` (again, replacing X) indicate that X is a child process of the process with ID X - 2?

If the process is indeed a background process spawned by 'ffmpeg', have you tried killing it?  That might be sufficient to kill the parent process as well.